# Android compass simple code do not work. How to fix it?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-4.4-kitkat, compass

I wrote application using this example
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html

But it does not work. If I rotate the phone the image just twitch.

I use Sony M2 (Android 4.4.4).

How to write simple compass?

Answer (score 0):

you can try my CompassAssistant class. It should do exactly what you want:

[CompassAssistant on GitHub](https://github.com/klein-artur/Simple-Android-Compass-Assistant)

If you want to try it by yourself I give you an example:

Let your activity implement the SensorEventListener and add the necessary fields:

```
public class CompassActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor magnetometer;
    private float[] lastAccelerometer = new float[3];
    private float[] lastMagnetometer = new float[3];
    private boolean lastAccelerometerSet = false;
    private boolean lastMagnetometerSet = false;
    private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    private float[] orientation = new float[3];
```

In the onCreate method of the activity get and start the two sensors, the accelerometer and the magnetometer:

```
        // onCreate method stub ...
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        // more onCreate method stub ....
```

In the method of the SensorEventListener you can now calculate the heading of the phone and calculate the bearing between the current location and a other location:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor == this.accelerometer) {
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, this.lastAccelerometer, 0, event.values.length);
            this.lastAccelerometerSet = true;
        } else if (event.sensor == this.magnetometer) {
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, this.lastMagnetometer, 0, event.values.length);
            this.lastMagnetometerSet = true;
        }

        if (this.lastAccelerometerSet && this.lastAccelerometerSet) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(this.rotationMatrix,null, this.lastAccelerometer, this.lastMagnetometer);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(this.rotationMatrix, this.orientation);


            float azimuthInRadiands = this.orientation[0];

            // this is now the heading of the phone. If you want
            // to rotate a view to north don´t forget that you have
            // to rotate by the negative value.
            float azimuthInDegrees = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadiands);

        }
    }
```

But don´t forget that there is much more behind a compass. You have to show the user if the magnetic field sensor is uncalibrated. You have to calculate the difference between the magnetic and the geographic north...

In my CompassAssistant this all is considered.